# Flutter - fonts behave differently on different versions of iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, fonts

I am developing an app with Flutter. When running our app in iPhoneX simulator - iOS version 13.5 everything works good.

In iPhoneX simulator with version **iOS 13.3**, all text with **fontWeight 300** do not render properly -  see photos attached. The fonts we are using is "Helvetica neue". What can cause this? could it be a problem with the font itself?

this is how we define the fonts in the pubspec.yml file:

```
- family: Halvetica
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica45Light.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica25UltraLight.ttf
      weight: 100
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica35Thin.ttf
      weight: 300
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica55Roman.ttf
      weight: 500
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica65Medium.ttf
      weight: 600
    - asset: fonts/Helvetica85Heavy.ttf
      weight: 700
```

This is how the font family is set:

```
var baseTextStyle = TextStyle(fontFamily: "Halvetica", color: AppColors.black);
```

I have a config where I create a custom theme:

```
class AppTheme {
 static ThemeData of(context) {
   var theme = Theme.of(context);
   return theme.copyWith(...); // Here I override the default theme
 }
}
```

[image: (]
[image]

Comment: Try doing a `flutter clean` before running the app once. Also post the part of code where you are setting `FontFamily`.

Comment: @dev-aentgs added in the original post

Comment: Try changing `Halvetica` to some other font, that way we will know is it font issue or something else.

Comment: it seems to happen only with the Halvetica Neue font. Why would this happen? Is there a way of fixing the font?

Comment: Assuming that rendering this font ios13.3 simulator is not supported that well. Try `var baseTextStyle = TextStyle(letterSpacing:0.0, fontFamily: "Halvetica", color: AppColors.black);` I dont know if this will show any difference, `letterSpacing` property should affect the in-betweeen space of each of the character.

Comment: yeah I tried it, it does not help (you can see that the spacing are not equal anyway and its totally random so it does not really help). Do you think it could be only issue in the simulator?

Comment: Yes, could be. Try on actual device if possible.